# How to write a Kinect plugin for web browser

Tags: plugins, web, kinect

I am new to web development. Can I get some pointers on how can I develop a kinect application in web browser?

Ideally it should be cross platform. I don't want to use paid third party plugins like Zigfu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing Kinect via a browser requires the user to install some kind of service on your client (PC or Mac). This service would then expose itself via the TCP networking stack so a browser-plug in can call back to it on the local host. Flash or Silverlight will use TCP natively. If you want to use HTML5 you can expose this service using web sockets or an AJAX-style service returning JSON data.

All-in-all it's a complicated solution that will never be globally supported for websites as there is no consistent  user-experience in getting people up and running with the hardware/service/installer. I would only use this in controlled envrionments; and instead look at rich client apps for a better Kinect experience.

Comment: I don't think Zigfu is using web services. Any idea how do they do it? I want to write a cross platform Kinect application. HTML5 + WebGL seems to be a good combination. I though of Openframeworks but I need to play hi resolution videos as well.

Comment: Zigfu use exactly this structure but they expose it via browser plug-ins instead of a service. They have then written their own developer kit over the top so you don't have to wire-up the service architecture but instead call into something more managed - in a similar fashion to NITE or Kinect for Windows. If you take a look at http://zigfu.com/en/downloads/browserplugin/ you are still required to also install Kinect drivers and SDK's so the experience is not seamless by any means.

Comment: If you want to do something cross-platform; take a look at Unity 3D. This is cross-platform game engine that compiles to OSX, Linux, and Windows. You can bundle up the executable with Kinect drivers/API's which will provide users a better install experience which aligns with how gaming/apps traditionally work (not a mess of unsigned browser plug-ins calling into hardware drivers).

Answer (score 1):

Zigfu uses http://www.firebreath.org/

I created Zigfu.

Comment: Your website is not working